# Setting local username when logging in with Azure AD

Tags: windows-10, entra-id

Is it possible to independently assign what is set as %username% when logging in to a computer that authenticates directly against Azure active directory services?

I'm trying to set things up with a minimal on site presence as this is for a small business (sub 50 users), and throwing an extra 4+ servers into the mix for a "proper" Active Directory Federated Services setup feels like overkill.

Comment: "Setting local username when logging in with Azure AD" What does this mean? Did you mean you want to use Azure AD account logs in to computers?

Comment: I already have that working, we have some software that validates licences against the %username% returned by windows. Right now we have usernames in the format <first initial><lastname> but when logged in using Azure AD the %username% returned seems to be the AD displayname stripped of spaces. I assume I could set up an on site domain controller, and then connect to azure ad and set up federation, but just using the azure would be preferred if possible.

Answer (score 0):

not sure exactly what you mean, but there is also variable %userdomain% and command whoami. It both shows AzureAD.